# how to modify wix DiskCostDlg message dynamically based on the disk size?

Tags: wix

I am using Wix for my installer. There is DiskCostDlg displayed once I select "Disk Usage" from CustomizeDlg.

Even though I have enough space, the text message displays,

“Highlighted volumes do not have enough disk space available for the currently selected features...”

Is there any way, I can modify this message dynamically?

I mean I would like to check if there is enough space and if yes, don't display this message. If there is no space, I would like to display the above message.

Any suggestions how to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

This can be done through control conditions:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368035(VS.85).aspx
- http://madtechnology.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/wix-enable-disable-controls-based-on-user-selection/
- http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/conditionally-enable-disable-control-part-2/

To determine if there is not enough free space you can check [OutOfDiskSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370564%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.